# Expectation of random variable times stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ by a jump-diffusion process and define $\tau = \inf\{t\geq 0 : X_t \geq B \}$ the first time that $X_t$ exceeds $B$. Let $C>0$. I am having trouble understanding intuitively what is the meaning of the expectation:

$$ E[X_\tau \mathbb{1}_{\tau \leq C}] $$

Where $X_t$ is stopped at $\tau$. I know I haven't given any details about the process $X_t$, but what would be the general guidelines for how to calculate such an expectation?

Comment: What do you mean by "jump-diffusion process"..?

Comment: @saz I mean I diffusion process with jumps, as in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_diffusion . I can change the question to just diffusion, maybe the meaning of the expectation is the same?